# Front End vs Back-End processing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, architecture, api-design

I'm ingesting a codebase that is a React-NodeJS stack. One of the concepts that I am trying to grasp is regarding the back-end API and how its handled client side.

The codebase is essentially dumping an entire collection from MongoDB with an API call, and then doing a good amount of parsing and client side logic with React in order to render custom views. The HTTP responses here are pretty large, and will only get larger as data is added to the DB.

Is there any advantage/disadvantage to this approach, as opposed to creating multiple endpoints in NodeJS, and utilizing something like Mongoose to return filtered data to the client, making rendering easy and responses smaller.

Things to take into consideration could be resource consumption, how this would be billed if in the cloud, the impact of SPA's, etc.

Hopefully i get some more clarity at the end of this?

Answer (score 0):

Client-side processing is best because as you know our server-side resources are free and can easily handle requests.but Sending large amounts of data to the client for processing will incur client overhead and make their browsing experience less acceptable, data security may be compromised, or the network may be overwhelmed and bandwidth consumed. Processing data server side will increase your server load per client.

So to avoid these issues, it is best to first hand over some of these conflicts to the side of the database handled (with filtering and special conditions) and then filter the security data processed in server side with command and coding that Do not send clients.

But let's do the heavy processing on the client machine. SPA has other benefits, of course.

So I mostly do server-side processing - unless it's really basic stuff like simple sorting etc etc.

Also, don't assume JavaScript is enabled. You have to fall back gracefully and that would require the server to do the processing anyhow.

this link say to you [differences between server-side and client-side programming](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)