# Output Dates in PHP for JS Datepicker - Highlight Dates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

have been looking on here for a couple of days but I'm not sure what my issue is. I have this php code to get dates from my DB

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    
    $php_array_dates = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row["date_date"]));/*Changes date to 23/03/2021*/
         
    $for_JS_date = "eventDates[ new Date("." '".$php_array_dates."' ".")] = new Date("." '".$php_array_dates."' ".");<BR>";
     
     //$formatted_JS_date = trim($formatted_JS_date, '"');
     
     
     echo $for_JS_date;
}
```

}

This outputs (it seems perfect) from **echo $for_JS_date;** this is just so I can see what's being produced.

```
eventDates[ new Date( '03/31/2021' )] = new Date( '03/31/2021' );
eventDates[ new Date( '03/29/2021' )] = new Date( '03/29/2021' );
eventDates[ new Date( '03/30/2021' )] = new Date( '03/30/2021' );
```

Now when I add the php variable  **$for_JS_date** to the jquery date picker it breaks the javascript even though it's the identicle format that I need. In fact if I manually write the dates produced by the php variable it works fine. It's probably something silly I'm doing but I'm at a loss. Below is the datepicker code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<style>   
.event a {
    background-color: #5FBA7D !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
</style>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>                                                                                
$( function() {

    // An array of dates
    var eventDates = {};
      /*eventDates[ new Date( '03/31/2021' )] = new Date( '03/31/2021' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '03/29/2021' )] = new Date( '03/29/2021' );
        eventDates[ new Date( '03/30/2021' )] = new Date( '03/30/2021' );*/
    
    
    <?php echo $for_JS_date; ?>
    
    // datepicker
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        
        /*###START### MONTH & YEAR MENUS ###START###*/
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        /*###END### MONTH & YEAR MENUS ###END###*/
        
        beforeShowDay: function( date ) {
            var highlight = eventDates[date];
            if( highlight ) {
                 return [true, "event", 'Tooltip text'];
            } else {
                 return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: In the first snippet, it appears you are doing `echo $for_JS_date;` _inside_ the loop, so one for each of those lines; in your second one there’s only one single `<?php echo $for_JS_date; ?>` left. So how is that supposed to match? Where did the loop go? Did you change anything about it, so that it accumulates the values into this single string variable now, instead of echo-ing them individually?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not quite sure what your saying but Saud below solved it. The php loop was producing what I needed but it was how I was reproducing it in the JS datepicker by including the <BR> instead of concatenating it with .=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript seems fine the error is in you PHP syntax. You first need to initialize a variable and then you need to concatenate to it. You're adding a `<BR>` tag in your string which could work if you print your string in HTML. Since you're printing your string in JavaScript it will generate an error. Because there is no such thing as `<BR>` in JavaScript. Here is an example of what your string is generating in JavaScript before executing it:

```
eventDates[ new Date( '03/22/2021' )] = new Date( '03/22/2021' );<BR>
```

As you can see this `<BR>` tag is just sitting there causing nothing but trouble. Here is what you need to modify to your code:

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $for_JS_date = null;

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $php_array_dates = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($row["date_date"]));/*Changes date to 23/03/2021*/
                
        $for_JS_date .= "eventDates[ new Date("." '".$php_array_dates."' ".")] = new Date("." '".$php_array_dates."' ".");";
    }
}
```

**What the above shown code would do?**

It will not replace your index in array, instead it will append into your array.

*P.s: There is a much better approach than this, But I'm just answering your original question!*

Comment: Thanks Saud, I would be interested in the different approach. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Timespider Yeah sure! In your approach you're generating the JavaScript code via PHP. You can instead tweak your code a bit and format your array at backend(PHP) and then send that fully formatted array to JavaScript and access it. How, you may ask? It's easy. I'll explain the best way I can, I hope you understand... :)

Comment: First initialize the variable with array `$for_JS_date = array();`. Then instead of `$for_JS_date = "eventDates...` you can do this `$for_JS_date[$php_array_dates] = $php_array_dates;`. And outside of `while` loop you need to `json_encode` this variable `json_encode($for_JS_date)`. And in JavaScript initialize it like this `let obj = <?= $for_JS_date ?>;` and access it like this `var highlight = obj[date];`

Comment: Thanks again, yes I can follow what you are saying(to the point I'll work on it - I'm a house builder so it takes time for me to work out). But I can see(I think) this is a cleaner way of getting the dates and inserting it into the JS.

Comment: @Timespider sure no problem. Remember always do any kind of processing at backend and just rendering at frontend. Minimalize the process at user's end unless you're building SPAs. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58183639/5082301) for clarification. Happy coding. :)